# How to create random number for Firebase data in quiz app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, random, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an Quiz app wherein questions and answers are taken from Firebase. I have uploaded questions with its options in Firebase and now want to retrieve them randomly. I have tried

```
Random number = new Random();
        number.nextInt(25);
```

The problem is I don't need repeats. I need one number to be generated only once and when questions end an alert bar should show and send user to score activity. Here is my main activity

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (mScore != 0){
    mScore = savedInstanceState.getInt("QK");

    }
    else{
        mScore = 0;

    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bioquiz);
    setAndroidContext(this);
    choice1b = findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    choice2b = findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    choice3b = findViewById(R.id.choice3);
    choice4b = findViewById(R.id.choice4);
    mScoreTextView = findViewById(R.id.Score);
    mQuestionTextView = findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);

        Random m = new Random();

    int mQuestionNo = m.nextInt(25);



    updateQuestion();
    View.OnClickListener A = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (choice1b.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                choice1b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore = mScore + 1;
                mScoreTextView.setText("Score "+String.valueOf(mScore) + "/"+ " 100");
                Toast.makeText(Bioquiz.this, "You got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateQuestion();
            } else {
                updateQuestion();
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                Toast.makeText(Bioquiz.this, "oops Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    };
    View.OnClickListener B = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (choice2b.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                choice1b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore = mScore + 1;
                mScoreTextView.setText("Score "+String.valueOf(mScore) + "/"+ " 100");
                Toast.makeText(Bioquiz.this, "You got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateQuestion();
            } else {
                updateQuestion();
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                Toast.makeText(Bioquiz.this, "oops Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    };
    View.OnClickListener C = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (choice4b.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                choice1b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore = mScore + 1;
                mScoreTextView.setText("Score "+String.valueOf(mScore) + "/"+ " 100");
                Toast.makeText(Bioquiz.this, "You got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateQuestion();
            } else {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                updateQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(Bioquiz.this, "oops Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener D = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (choice4b.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                choice1b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore = mScore + 1;
                mScoreTextView.setText("Score "+String.valueOf(mScore) + "/"+ " 100");
                Toast.makeText(Bioquiz.this, "You got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateQuestion();

            } else {

                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                updateQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(Bioquiz.this, "oops Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    };
    choice1b.setOnClickListener(A);
    choice2b.setOnClickListener(B);
    choice3b.setOnClickListener(C);
    choice4b.setOnClickListener(D);

}

    public void updateQuestion() {
        Random number = new Random();
        number.nextInt(25);



    Firebase questionRef = new Firebase("https://mcatbiologymcqs.firebaseio.com/"+mQuestionNo+"/question");
    questionRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String question = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
    Firebase choice1Ref = new Firebase("https://mcatbiologymcqs.firebaseio.com/" +mQuestionNo + "/choice1");
    choice1Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            choice1b.setText(choice1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
    mChoice2Ref = new Firebase("https://mcatbiologymcqs.firebaseio.com/"+mQuestionNo+"/choice2");
    mChoice2Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            choice2b.setText(choice2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
    mChoice3Ref = new Firebase("https://mcatbiologymcqs.firebaseio.com/"+mQuestionNo+"/choice3");
    mChoice3Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice3 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            choice3b.setText(choice3);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
    mChoice4Ref = new Firebase("https://mcatbiologymcqs.firebaseio.com/"+mQuestionNo+"/choice4");
    mChoice4Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice4 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            choice4b.setText(choice4);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
    Firebase answerRef = new Firebase("https://mcatbiologymcqs.firebaseio.com/"+mQuestionNo+"/answer");
    answerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mAnswer = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    if (mScoreTextView == null){

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Quiz Over");
        if (mScore ==20){alert.setMessage("Very Good");}
        else {
            alert.setMessage("You need to Work Hard");
        }
        alert.setPositiveButton("View Score", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           Intent score = new Intent(Bioquiz.this,Score.class);

           startActivity(score);
            }
        });
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();


        }
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent m = new Intent(Bioquiz.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(m);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("SK",mScore);





}}
```

Comment: From the fact that you use `new Firebase(...` it seems like you're using an SDK that is 2½ years old. Please consider [upgrading to the latest SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to get a random question out of a possible 25 questions and don't want to get the same question twice.  You could keep a list of question numbers and remove the question number from the list once the user has seen that question.

```
//declare the list at the top with the other variables
public List<Integer> questionNos = new ArrayList<>();
```

in onCreate change this line

```
int mQuestionNo = m.nextInt(25);
```

to these lines

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
    questionNos.add(i);
}
Random r = new Random();
    int index = r.nextInt(questionNos.size()-1);
    int mQuestionNo = questionNos.remove(index);
```

in updateQuestion() change these lines

```
Random number = new Random();
number.nextInt(25);
```

to this

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int index = r.nextInt(questionNos.size()-1);
    int number = questionNos.remove(index);
```

That should get you most of the way there.  You may need to save the list in onPause and load it in onResume for when your app is stopped or rotated.

Comment: Bundle of thanks sir, can you please tell me where to implement this in my activity. I totally confused. If you have time I will be thankful.

Comment: in my updateQuestion I have added mQuestionNo=number works like charm thanks dude :)

Comment: Getting this runtime error app crashes
Process: com.apkfeast.mcatbiologymcqs, PID: 16900
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 14, size is 14
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)

Comment: Ah, I guess I had the index off by 1.  Updated.

Comment: still crashes " java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=-1"
int number = questionNos.remove(index-1);
my database starts from 0 please screenshots here [link](https://ibb.co/jDojSU)

Comment: Hmmm...I guess I adjusted the wrong number.  Try it now.

Comment: Still crashes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: -1
at int index = r.nextInt(questionNos.size()-1);

Answer (score -1):

If you want to generate a unique you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of using `number = new Random(); number.nextInt(25);`

**Example:**

```
//Random m = new Random();
long mQuestionNo = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: Bro i am a starter can show write these lines for me?

Comment: 'long mQuestionNo = System.currentTimeMillis();' 
not generating any random number